# Azure search : Proximity search with wild cards

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Proximity with phrase search using wild cards is not maintaining the order and giving the wrong result

I am trying to search **“Bal* Peti*”~5** for which the result should have both the specified words in the same order within a proximity of 5.

but the result doesnt respect the order and both the specified words arent available in few  cases.

Answer (score 0):

The proximity operator ~ defines how many transpositions of phrase query terms are allowed. Currently the proximity operator does not support wildcards.

Let's look at a few phrase queries and one document has three terms on subsequent positions: A B C

"A B" will match - this is equivalent to "A B"~0
"A C"~1 will match - term C moved forward by one position
"C B" won't match
"C B"~1 won't match - with only one allowed transposition we can move terms B and C to the same position
"C B"~2 will match - by allowing two transpositions the terms can reverse order of the phrase query terms

We don't have immediate plans to change this behavior, please vote on our [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) page to help us prioritize.